# PhpStorm ignores PHPDoc for arrays of

Tags: php, phpstorm, type-hinting

I have a parameter that is supposed to be `string[]`. However PhpStorm does not care what is inside the array as long as it is an array.

```
class Slack {
    /**
     * @param string[] $emails
     */
    public static function export($emails) : void {}
}

Slack::export([1,2,3]);
Slack::export(['1','2','3']);
```

It should complain about `Slack::export([1,2,3]);` but it does not.

Comment: Complain to JetBrains -- file ticket at their Issue Tracker.

Comment: @LazyOne I was just wondering if someone could check if this is the expected behavior. (I.e. a bug), or if it is just on my machine

Comment: It's not a machine specific bug/yuor setting. It's just the way how IDE handles such stuff -- it's not that strict as you expecting (as it does not check the type of each array element). I very doubt that this particular example will be treated as a bug -- more like Feature Request (AFAIK such check is not super trivial and requires some CPU time etc)

Comment: @LazyOne Ah, I see. Autocompletion works. So I guess it's really just too 'lazy' to check for array contents. I was expecting too much from being spoiled by typescript :)

Comment: The root of the issue -- the legacy of PHP and the fact that some strictness possibilities in the language itself were added pretty recently (few years); not too many public libraries/frameworks even use strict mode inside them etc. If you make IDE that strict -- there will be many complaints as there always will be some incompatibilities/wrong doc etc (for some people just presence of PHPDoc is already "badly written  code"). So while in TypeScript it has strictness in mind from the start ... here in PHP it's other way around/lots of old code etc.

Comment: Another thing: every inspection requires some CPU/RAM resources. Depending on a computer hardware and project itself (how code is written/what technologies/frameworks used etc) .. the IDE may become quite slow... I do not know what PhpStorm devs may say about such new/improved inspection .. but you may also try submitting such Feature Request here: https://github.com/kalessil/phpinspectionsea/issues -- may appear in that plugin.

Comment: PHP has an array type, but not typed arrays. An array can hold any combination of any type. If you want to be strict about what an array contains you need to check every element, or implement some sort of collection class that has type checking built in and type hint on that.